# Irreducible representation of $S_3$ on $\mathbb C^3$

Tags: representation-theory

Does there exists an irreducible representation of the group $S_3$ on $\mathbb C^3$? The representations that I can think of all have a $1$ dimensional subspaces that are fixed.

Comment: There are two $1$-dimension irreducible representations and at least one $2$-dimensional representation (since $S_3$ is also the set of symmetries on a triangle.) The sum of the degrees of the irreducible representations of a finite group is, if I recall correctly, the size of the finite group. Am I mis-remembering that? If so, there can't be an irreducible $3$-dimensional representation.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Ah, as I was writing! Sum of *squared* degrees :) Er, well, I come from a character theory, not representation theory, background. Maybe we're saying the same thing.

Comment: Ah, so I found them all :) @pjs36

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: The sum of squared degrees of irreducible characters is the order of the group. That is, given $Irr(G)$, the set of irreducible representations of $G$ over $\mathbb{C}$,

$$\sum_{\mathcal{X} \in Irr(G)} tr(\mathcal{X}(1))^2 = |G|,$$ where $|Irr(G)|$ is the number of conjugacy classes of $G$.

It does have a representation from its action on the set $\{1, 2, 3\}$, but it won't be irreducible.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much!