# Irreducible representation from $S_3$ to $GL_n$

Tags: representation-theory

I want to know why for any irreducible representation $\phi: S_3 \to GL_n(\mathbb{C})$, $n$ is either $1$ or $2$. In what way can we see this is true?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Irreducible representation of $S_3$ on $\mathbb C^3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1193351/irreducible-representation-of-s-3-on-mathbb-c3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the group algebra $\mathbb{C}[G]$ (for finite group) decomposes

$$\mathbb{C}[G] = \bigoplus_{i\in \mathrm{Irr}(G)}V_i^{\oplus d_i}$$

as a left module over itself, where $d_i=\mathrm{dim}(V_i)$. This follows from Maschke and Wedderburn-Artin theorems. It follows that

$$|G| =\mathrm{dim}(\mathbb{C}[G]) = \sum_{i\in \mathrm{Irr}(G)}d_i^2$$

In particular, for $G=S_3$ if $d_{i_0}\geq 3$ for some $i_0\in \mathrm{Irr}(G)$, then

$$9 \leq d_{i_0}^2\leq \sum_{i\in \mathrm{Irr}(G)}d_i^2 = |S_3| = 6$$